# how to get the proraw image output with 1:1, 16:9

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation, raw

Now I use AVFoundation framework to get the photo output, but the image aspect ratio is 4:3. But according to the Camera app in the iPhone 13 Pro, it has server image aspect ratio: 4:3, 16:9 and 1:1 when take the proraw image. So how can I get the 1:1, 16:9 aspect ratio proraw image?

After I do some research, I find that no matter you use which kinds of camera in the iPhone 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 or Pro, the result image is always 4:3, 1:1 and 16:9 come from the 4:3 cropping. If it is true, how can I crop the proraw file without any data lossing?

My developer environment:

iPhone 13 Pro
iOS 16.7
xcode 14.3.1

This is the session configuration and device output code for the camera.
https://gist.github.com/qihuijia/5fc78cdd6cece965929e5995713f0ac9

After I tried it, the result image aspect ratio is still 4:3

Comment: You should include all relevant code (in the form of a [mcve]) in the body of your question rather than linked through an external site.

Comment: You never crop raw file images, the cropping takes place when you convert to jpeg, heic etc. What is done when you select an aspect ratio is that it is stored in the raw image file's metadata.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson when I use the app Camera app, I can crop the raw file. Then after cropping, it still is raw file. So how does it achieve that?

Comment: _"I can crop the raw file"_, what do you mean?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It mean that when I use apple Camera app, after I take the raw photo, I can crop it from 4:3 to 16:9. I can show you the screen recording.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ltbn2t68z13dr4dbbwqmx/RPReplay_Final1698304231.MP4?rlkey=k6ox51k8p4cp0l39qs6o4c2vf&dl=0
@JoakimDanielson you can see this video. This is the apple camera app, not my app

Comment: I am not talking about what you do with your camera but about your code. And again, it's not the raw file itself that is cropped when you crop in the camera. When you crop then the camera app create a cropped image in another format (HEIC or jpeg) with that ratio but the original raw file is unchanged.